# Stop Lambda Triggers

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have some records in dynamoDB and trigger associated with it configured via serverless.yml file.

Below the configuration `events:
      - stream:
          type: dynamodb
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - myTable
              - StreamArn
          batchSize: 1`

But I have a requirement that based on some flag, I should stop the execution of all records (lambda)  if one record ends in failure and subsequently all the records for that transaction has to be deleted from dynamoDB.

I noticed that even after deleting the records from DynamodB, the trigger still continues, Please is there a way to get the exisiting triggers with respect to the context and stop all  ?

P.S I am using Nodejs

Code and Steps

Checker.js -- Talks to external system and adds the records to the dynamoDB table specified and exits. The below function Validate data is called via events from dynamodB. The serverless configuration for it is below

```
  ValidateData :
handler: ValidateData.handler
memorySize: 1536
timeout: 300
events:
  - stream:
      type: dynamodb
      arn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - kpiTaskTable
          - StreamArn
      batchSize: 1
```

ValidateData --

```
 async.waterfall([
        //go get kpis
        function getKPIs(next) {
            request({
                agent: agent,
                uri: getKPIsURL(endpoint, APIKey),
                maxAttempts: retryCount,
                retryDelay: retryDelayTime,
                retryStrategy: request.RetryStrategies.HTTPOrNetworkError
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("ERROR:Error whilst fetching KPI's: " + error);
                    next(error);
                } else {
                    //need to add in here to check that at least one kpi was returned otherwise error
                    kpis = JSON.parse(body);
                    if (kpis.constructor != Array) {
                        console.log("ERROR:Error KPI's are not of type Array");
                        next(error);
                    } else {
                        next(null);
                    }
                }
            });
        }................................

    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: Something has gone wrong: " + err)
            var stopReportGen = process.env.STOP_REPORT_CREATION_ON_ERROR;
            if (stopReportGen === "true") {
                console.log("Deleting records from dynamoDB for report ID " + reportId);

                kpiUtil.deleteRecordsFromDynamoDB(reportId).then(function () {
                    s3Api.deleteFile(reportBucket, reportName, retryCount, retryDelayTime).then(function () {
                        console.log("INFO : The temp file is deleted from the S3 bucket")
                        callback(null, "ERROR: " + sourceId + "Report ID :" + reportId);
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        console.log("ERROR : Error in deleting the temp file from the S3 bucket")
                        callback(null, "ERROR:  " + sourceId + "Report ID :" + reportId);
                    })
                });

            }
```

Delete From Dynamodb  -- Deleting the records from DB

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var fs = require('fs');

(function (exports) {
deleteRecordsFromDynamoDB = function (reportId) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
        var table = process.env.KPI_TASK_TABLE;

        var params = {
            TableName: table,
            FilterExpression: "#reportId = :reportId_val",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#reportId": "reportId",
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":reportId_val": parseInt(reportId) }

        };

        docClient.scan(params, onScan);
        var count = 0;

        function onScan(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("ERROR: Error, Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Scan succeeded for reportID ::"+reportId);
                data.Items.forEach(function (itemdata) {
                    var delParams = {
                        TableName: table,
                        Key: {
                            "reportSource": itemdata.reportSource
                        }
                    };

                    console.log("Attempting a conditional delete...");
                    docClient.delete(delParams, function (err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error("ERROR:Error, Unable to delete item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log("DeleteItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                        }
                    });
                    console.log("INFO:Item :", ++count, JSON.stringify(itemdata));



                });

                // continue scanning if we have more items
                if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
                    console.log("Scanning for more...");
                    params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                    docClient.scan(params, onScan);
                }else{
                    resolve("sucess");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
exports.deleteRecordsFromDynamoDB = deleteRecordsFromDynamoDB;
}(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? this['deleteRecordsFromDynamoDB'] = {} :    exports))
```

Comment: you can use promise.all , update question with some code if you need code in answer

Comment: Added the code, Please can you check

Comment: When you detect the bad condition, you could immediately write a known value to a different DynamoDB table (like ignore_events=true) and each Lambda function is responsible for checking this before it actually acts on a DynamoDB stream event. That would hopefully cause any subsequent, undesirable Lambda invocations to be no-ops. Also, of course, you might want to remove the event notification that's actually triggering the Lambda functions, until the underlying bad condition has been rectified..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the above description, my understanding is that deleting the items will create the streams to lambda as well. You can ignore the delete streams in two ways:-

1) Check for `eventName` in Record. If the `eventName` is `REMOVE`, you can potentially ignore the stream in Lambda function

2) Before deleting the items in Dynamodb, please disable the stream on DynamoDB table using `Update Table API`.

Please note that Update Table is asynchronous operation. So it will take a while to reflect the change. The items should not be deleted until the stream is disabled. Otherwise, you can implement both option 1 and 2 to be in safer side.

```
var params = {
  TableName: "SomeTableName",
  StreamSpecification: {
    StreamEnabled: false    
  }
 };
 dynamodb.updateTable(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);  
 }
```

You may need to enable the stream when you would like to have the Lambda trigger back in operation.

Comment: Thanks , I tried a similar kind of solution and it worked,

Comment: Good. Would you like to upvote so that it will be helpful for others?